# Downloading Movies on Google Play in HD

Tags: ipad

I can't download Google Play Movies in HD on my iPad Pro.  It streams it in HD, but it won't download it in HD, and I can't find a setting that chooses one way or the other.

Comment: Hope you have checked this:https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2851696?hl=en-GB

Answer (score -1):

Download videos to your iPad:

1. Make sure your device is connected to Wi-Fi or your mobile network.
2. Open the Google Play Movies & TV app Play Movies [image].
3. Tap Menu [image] Library.
4. Next to the movie or TV episode, you’d like to download, touch the download icon [image].

Note: To remove or stop a download in progress, tap the download icon again.

Source: [Google Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2851696?hl=en-GB)

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.  I know how to download videos.  What I'm saying is that the videos I download aren't in HD quality like they are when I'm streaming them.  The files only download in SD quality.  You can also tell by how small the file sizes are.